# PHP—Namespace + echo = no output

Tags: php, namespaces, output

I have this code:

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  namespace App\Item;

  echo 'foo';
```

Nothing is »echoed«. If I remove the `namespace` it works. `\echo 'foo'` does not work either. No Warnings, no Errors, so whats wrong?

```
phpinfo(); //also not showing anything with the namespace

> PHP Version 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.10.1
```

Comment: Not particularly used to namespaces however I've heard of problems like this being solved by putting the namespace as the first line of code.

Comment: **Namespaces are declared using the namespace keyword. A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code - with one exception: the declare keyword.** [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php)

Comment: when I run the code I get: `Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in...`.

Comment: Also this is a "compile time" error so your `ini_set` will not run at all. If you actually want to see the errors modify your actual php.ini file.

Comment: Thanks all! Putting the namespace declaration at the top resolved the problem. Thanks for help! I just forgot that…